# (Chromium) alpha color value (in rgba) in CSS and javascript

Tags: javascript, css, chromium

If I set the alpha value via rgba(r, g, b, a) in javascript to anything other than 1, the actual value set by browser is slightly different. But value set in CSS is an exact match.

See code sample in 
[code-pen-site](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/aNzapr)

```
    <head>    
      <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
        window.onload=function() {
        document.getElementById("p1").style["background-color"]="rgba(255,0,0,0.3)";
        }
      </script>
    </head>

    <body>
      <p>RGB colors with opacity:</p>
      <p id="p1">Red</p>
      <p id="p2">Green</p>
    </body>
```

1. use Chromium browser
2. press F12 to activate Inspector
3. Inspect "Red".
4. "Red" has background-color set to rgba(255,0,0,0.3), but in Inspector its value is rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.298039)
5. "Green" has background-color set to rgba(0,255,0,0.3), and value in Inspector matches that.

Why if CSS color is set via Javascript then the number changes?

Comment: it seems that chrome is summing to the alpha value a `+/- 0.001961` constant when it is defined with a single decimal. also with more decimals the value changes again. It seems a bug

Answer (score 2):

First, my original observation is incorrect. If you click on the "Computed" tab to inspect the background-clor, this difference is observed for both CSS rules inside 'style' tag and inline within elements.  I

In [chromium source code](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/f94944ad723e8a0cbee71258960394d17f32adef/third_party/WebKit/Source/core/css/parser/CSSPropertyParser.cpp)
this implementation explains the 0.001961 difference in the alpha value

```
// Convert the floating pointer number of alpha to an integer in the range [0, 256),
// with an equal distribution across all 256 values.
int alphaComponent = 
    static_cast<int>(
        clampTo<double>(alpha, 0.0, 1.0) * nextafter(256.0, 0.0));
```

Here if alpha is 0.3, then alphaComponent becomes 0.298039.  (If I set alpha to any floating point in [0.0, 1.0] the number shown by webInspector matches the alphaComponent value acquired from above formula.